# How to get string from resource to my dummy data source as mutable list

Tags: android, string, kotlin, mobile, frontend

Im so confused how to load string from resource to mutable list, cause i wanna make localization on my project

```
interface DummyMateriDataSource {
    fun getMateriData(): List<Materi>
}

class DummyMateriDataSourceImpl() : DummyMateriDataSource {
    override fun getMateriData(): List<Materi> {
        return mutableListOf(
            Materi(
                imgUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ryhanhxx/img_asset/main/img_kalkulator.webp",
                title = "Lorem",
                heading = "",
                desc = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. ",
                subHeading = "",
                subDesc = "",
                source = ""
            ),
         )
    }
}
```

I wanna load from my resource String like this, but idk how to, its still error, please help guys hehe.

```
interface DummyMateriDataSource {
    fun getMateriData(): List<Materi>
}

class DummyMateriDataSourceImpl() : DummyMateriDataSource {
    override fun getMateriData(): List<Materi> {
        return mutableListOf(
            Materi(
                imgUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ryhanhxx/img_asset/main/img_kalkulator.webp",
                title = getString(R.string.txt_materi),
                heading = getString(R.string.txt_materi),
                desc = getString(R.string.txt_materi),
                subHeading = getString(R.string.txt_materi),
                subDesc = getString(R.string.txt_materi),
                source = getString(R.string.txt_materi)
            ),
         )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you have to do it with the help of resources cause it is part of your resources
you have to write like this

resources.getString(R.string.txt_materi),

If you are in adater than you have to get string by giving your context so it would work like
context.resources.getString(R.string.yourstring)

Answer (score 0):

Your hehe got me xd here try this one

```
 interface DummyMateriDataSource {
        fun getMateriData(context: Context): List<Materi>
    }

class DummyMateriDataSourceImpl : DummyMateriDataSource {
    override fun getMateriData(context: Context): List<Materi> {
        val title = context.getString(R.string.txt_materi)
        return mutableListOf(
            Materi(
                imgUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ryhanhxx/img_asset/main/img_kalkulator.webp",
                title = title,
                heading = title,
                desc = title,
                subHeading = title,
                subDesc = title,
                source = title
            )
        )
    }
}
```

And then when you call getMateriData(), make sure to pass the context:

```
val dataSource = DummyMateriDataSourceImpl()
val materiList = dataSource.getMateriData(context)
```

Replace context with the actual context from where you're calling this method, such as an activity or fragment context. Make sure you import android.content.Context where necessary.